# SQLAlchemy and Insertion with joins

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to populate a database which has a table with a one-to-many relationship with another table. A basic example would be:

```
class File(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Files'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = ...

class Package(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Package'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    file_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Files.id'), nullable=False)
    title = ...
```

Since the Files table is 'independent' I start adding them

```
file1 = File(title='...')
file2 = File(title='...')

session.add(file1)
session.add(file2)
```

Then I can add packages and this is where the problem comes:

```
pkg1 = Package(file_id = file1.id, title='pkg1')
pkg2 = Package(file_id = file1.id, title='pkg2')

session.add(pkg1) # will fail
session.add(pkg2) # will fail too
```

it fails because `file1.id` is `None`. Currently to prevent this from happening I commit the database after adding files.

I would like if there is a better way of inserting data inside the database that would not require a commit. (I used a commit but making a query also updates `file1.id` to `1`). I also tried to use `session.refresh(file1, ['id'])` but I got an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Instance '<File at 0x34a5a70>' is not persistent within this Session
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is to use `session.flush()` after you've added the file objects to the session - that will populate your file objects with their ids.

However, since you're using the declarative stuff you may as well take advantage of relationships and avoid having to think about ids.

```
class File(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Files'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = ...

class Package(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Package'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    file_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Files.id'), nullable=False)
    title = ...

    file = relationship('File', backref='packages')

file1 = File(title='...')
# notice that we can now link the package to the file without having to think
# about ids - we're thinking in terms of the _objects_
pkg1 = Package(title='pkg1', file=file1)

# file1 will be automatically added
session.add(pkg1)
```

Comment: Very nice, Modified it. Removed half the line of code I wrote. Works like a charm. Thanks